# SQL Server 2008 Error: The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

I am getting the ERROR.

> The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived
>   tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP or FOR
>   XML is also specified.

This is the query:

```
select * from
   (select * from pacesetter_forecast order by hectare DESC) t 
group by cluster
```

Comment: Your statement doesn't make sense. What is the *real* problem you are trying to achieve?

Comment: You can't use group by with `select *` either, since you need to have aggregates for the other columns except cluster

Comment: Explain what you think ordering and grouping are supposed to do. I think you're confused about something.

Answer (score 1):

The error message is right. You cannot sort the output of a subquery. In case you are unsure what a subquery is:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT * FROM SomeOtherTable) T -- This is the subquery, a query within a query
```

Logically, it doesn't make much sense to order the results of a subquery. Generally, the idea of a subquery is you're taking the results of a query and using it like a table (`JOIN`ing to it, `SELECT`ing from it, etc). The order in which your rows in your tables are physically stored on disk is usually of little consequence until a human looks at the output.

As an aside, in your example above, your subquery is actually unnecessary. You can do your `GROUP BY` and `ORDER BY` simply by `SELECT`ing from your table, `pacesetter_forecast` (provided your table, has the proper schema that will allow `SELECT *` and `GROUP`ing by a single column name.. but that is a different discussion for another SO question).